# Sending image in ajax with without form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send an image with a Telegram message using ajax. I can send it ok using Postman and it gave me generated code to use with jQuery.

However I do not have a form to input the image. The image is instead in the same directory as the javascript file. I have tried just using the filename but I get a 400 `Bad Request` error.

```
        var message = `image caption`;

        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("photo", "image.png");
        form.append("chat_id", "xxxx");
        form.append("caption", message);

        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_bot_id + "/sendPhoto",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
            "processData": false,
            "data": form
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: So _Server_ serves html + javascript & _Client_ executes this code in an attempt to retrieve `image.png` from the _Server_ & then send that `image.png` file as an AJAX request? Yeah, can't do that if that is your intent. You'll beed two AJAX requests, one to _Server_ to retrieve `image.png` and the second as you have written but using the retrieved image.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the context of the image file and convert it to base64 and add it to your data as a string data

```js
  let imgStr =  fs.readFileSync("Image File Path","utf-8");
  let imgBase64 = btoa(imgStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a file input control to get access to any file on the client machine.

```
    <input id="the-file-input-id" type="file" name="photo"/>
```

Also, some of the settings are incorrect

```
    var form = new FormData();
    var img = $('#the-file-input-id').prop('files')[0];
    form.append("photo", img);
    form.append("chat_id", "xxxx");
    form.append("caption", message);

    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_bot_id + "/sendPhoto",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          //"Content-Type": "application/json", you are not sending json
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        //"mimeType": "multipart/form-data", this is not a real parameter
        "processData": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "data": form
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

This should work assuming the api supports CORS.

Comment: Unfortunately the api does not support CORS, I can not have an input